# Помогите дописать код!

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui, c#-8.0

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ShowAndHide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Object;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            Debug.Log("Q key was pressed.");
            Object.SetActive(!Object.activeSelf);
            Cursor.visible = !Cursor.visible;
        }
    }
}
```

**Нужно чтобы курсор откреплялся от экрана, если он закреплён, и закреплялся, если он откреплён.**

помогите!

Comment: Этот код не работает? Ну добавьте в конец своего if `Cursor.lockState = Cursor.visible ? CursorLockMode.None : CursorLockMode.Locked;`